# list all products of main category and subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I have 2 tables:

categories

```
id - name - parent
1 - Category 1 - 0
2 - Category 2 - 0
3 - Category 3 - 0
4 - Category 4 - 0
5 - Subcategory 11 - 1
6 - Subcategory 111 - 5
7 - Subcategory 112 - 5
...
```

products

```
id - name - category - description
1 - Name - 5 - Description
```

In categories table I have 3 levels

- Category 1

  - Subcategory 11
  - Subcategory 111
  - Subcategory 112
  - Subcategory 113
- Subcategory 12

  - Subcategory 121
  - Subcategory 122
  - Subcategory 123
  - Subcategory 13
- Category 2
- Category 3

I select products from Subcategories with:

```
mysql_query("SELECT *, products.name AS p_name, categories.name AS c_name
FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = products.category
WHERE categories.id = '". $_GET['items'] ."'
GROUP BY products.id DESC");
```

Products are in third level of categories(Subcategory 111, Subcategory 112, Subcategory 113, Subcategory 121...)

How to view all products from this categories also when I access parent category or main category(Category 1, Category 2, Subcategory 11, Subcategory 12...) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Err, so what is your question? What code are you having a problem with?

Comment: How is the category hierarchy managed: a self-join in the categories table, an edges table?

Comment: Captain, sorry! I need to view the products from subcategories when I acces main Category...

Comment: can you show your code here which you have tried..

Comment: I have edited the post with the code that I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of levels of hierarchy are known or assumed, you can do something like:

```
Select Root.name
    , Level1.name As Level1Category
    , Level2.name As Level2Category
From Category As Root
    Left Join Category As Level1
        On Level1.parent = Root.id
    Left Join Category As Level2
        On Level2.parent = Level1.id
Where Root.parent = 0
Order By Root.name, Level1.name, Level2.name
```

To then view the products you would simply join on products to any level of the hierarchy:

```
Select Root.name
    , Level1.name As Level1Category
    , Level2.name As Level2Category
    , P.name As ProductName
From Category As Root
    Left Join Category As Level1
        On Level1.parent = Root.id
    Left Join Category As Level2
        On Level2.parent = Level1.id
    Join Products As P
        On P.category = Root.id
            Or P.category = Level1.id
            Or P.category = Level2.id
Where Root.parent = 0
Order By Root.name, Level1.name, Level2.name, P.name
```

Comment: Now it's work on parent categories @Thomas, but when I enter in a third category it list all products ... not only from that categories... `SELECT *, root.name, level1.name AS level1category, level2.name AS level2category, p.name AS p_name FROM categories AS root LEFT JOIN categories AS level1 ON level1.parent = root.id LEFT JOIN categories AS level2 ON level2.parent = level1.id JOIN products AS p ON p.category = root.id OR p.category = level1.id OR p.category = level2.id WHERE root.parent = 13 ORDER BY root.name, level1.name, level2.name, p.name`

Comment: changed `WHERE root.parent = 13` with `WHERE root.parent = '". $_GET['items'] ."'` and now when I enter in 3thid level, not products listed...

Comment: I found `WHERE root.id = '". $_GET['items'] ."'`, fixed! Thanks @Thomas!

Comment: why I can't display category level 1 name? I use `echo $row['level1category'];` and the value it's empty... Any ideea?

Comment: @zmeutz - I'm not sure what filtering you are now using however, it should never be the case that you get say a Level 2 category without a Level 1 category given the design of my query.

Comment: I have found a solution, I used $_GET to get url... I'm trying to use full category location on products and categories. When I enter on a product to see details I need to see final category and parent categories of product category.